# How to properly display links in multiple sitemap

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I am generating multiple sitemap files and using sitemap index with Opencart framework.

$type are product, category, information

$page are numbers

```
          $output .= '  <sitemap>';
          $output .= '    <loc>' .$this->url->link('feed/google_sitemap/'.$type, ($page ? 'page='.$page++ : '')).'</loc>';
          $output .= '    <lastmod>'. date('Y-m-d') .'</lastmod>';
          $output .= '  </sitemap>';
```

at the end im getting result like this (everything work fine)

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>http://localhost/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/product&amp;page=1</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-20</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://localhost/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/product&amp;page=2</loc>
 <lastmod>2019-08-20</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

is it matter if links look like that ?

```
<loc>http://localhost/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/product&amp;page=2</loc>
```

or they should look something like

```
<loc>http://localhost/sitemap-product-1</loc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important the location in `<loc>` is a valid url. As it is displayed above, it would read as:

http://localhost/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/product&page=2

If you visit this url, do you get the content?
Most likely the `&` character should be replaced by `?`

Comment: yes im getting the content of page=2

Comment: Then it's fine, the sitemap is correct.

Comment: if in your url you have one character `?` (you already have before `route`), character `&` can not be replaced by `?`.

Comment: @K. B. sorry i didnt get you, what you mean ?

Comment: @ Paul have said "If you visit this url, do you get the content? Most likely the & character should be replaced by ?", so that is not truth.